# IAsyncDisposable reference implementation error?

Tags: c#, async-await, dispose, idisposable

Microsoft provides a refence implementation for classes that need to implement both IDisposable and IAsyncDisposable, say because they have members of both of these.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/implementing-disposeasync

I include the full implementation below. These lines in `Dispose(disposing)` are the part I don't understand.

```cs
(_asyncDisposableResource as IDisposable)?.Dispose();
...
_asyncDisposableResource = null;
```

It seems like if I have an instance of `CustomDisposable` and `Dispose()` gets called on it before `DisposeAsync()` then the `_asyncDispoableResource` field will have `Dispose()` called on it instead of `DisposeAsync` (if it has one), and then get set to null unconditionally. Seems like `_asyncDispoableResource` never gets disposed of properly in this case, even if `DisposeAsync()` gets called on the `CustomDisposable` instance later.

Full reference code:

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Samples
{
    public class CustomDisposable : IDisposable, IAsyncDisposable
    {
        IDisposable _disposableResource = new MemoryStream();
        IAsyncDisposable _asyncDisposableResource = new MemoryStream();

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(disposing: true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

        public async ValueTask DisposeAsync()
        {
            await DisposeAsyncCore();

            Dispose(disposing: false);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                _disposableResource?.Dispose();
                (_asyncDisposableResource as IDisposable)?.Dispose();
            }

            _disposableResource = null;
            _asyncDisposableResource = null;
        }

        protected virtual async ValueTask DisposeAsyncCore()
        {
            if (_asyncDisposableResource is not null)
            {
                await _asyncDisposableResource.DisposeAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
            }

            if (_disposableResource is IAsyncDisposable disposable)
            {
                await disposable.DisposeAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
            else
            {
                _disposableResource.Dispose();
            }

            _asyncDisposableResource = null;
            _disposableResource = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the purpose of the SuppressFinalize calls?

Comment: The dispose pattern indicates that there should also be a finalizer that calls `this.Dispose(true)`. It is omitted from this example. So, you suppress the finalizer to make sure that you don't try to dispose of already disposed resources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting your reference:

> It is typical when implementing the IAsyncDisposable interface that classes will also implement the IDisposable interface. A good implementation pattern of the IAsyncDisposable interface is to be prepared for either synchronous or asynchronous dispose.

This means that it should be sufficient to dispose an object via "classic" `Dispose`, it should not matter that `DisposeAsync` is never called. This is why the resource is set to `null`, so it is clear that it has already been disposed asynchonously. The actual implementation of the disposable reference has to be prepared for this.

Comment: But `IAsyncDisposable` does not implement `IDisposable`, so this cast may fail `(_asyncDisposableResource as IDisposable)?.Dispose();`, in which case the async resource will never get disposed

Comment: The recommendation is that any **implementation** should also implement `IDisposable`, in which case it would work. Like I wrote, it is up to the implementation to consider this recommendation. You are correct that it can fail if the implementation does not consider it.

Comment: Alex: Is the idea here that the caller will choose either to dispose synchronously or asynchronously, but ever both? And whichever they choose everything gets cleaned up?

Comment: It makes sense that you would not dispose an async disposable during a non-async Dispose() call.  I don't see the logic in not disposing the non-async disposable during the AsyncDispose call.   But the bigger question in my mind is what about finalizers.  It would seem to make no sense to have an AsyncDisposable with a finalizers.  it would be nice to have guidance on that.

Comment: @AdamV.Steele in my interpretation, a caller can choose how they want to dispose. It should not matter if they dispose sync, async, or both. Which is why the reference implementation does `null` checks even for the sync dispose, in case it is called in addition to async dispose.

Comment: Yeah I'd say you have answered it in that you understand MS's intent.  Seems like they could clarify and refine this refence design as it is pretty confusing to folks.